# CentOS 6 interfaces bonding, round-robin instead of active-backup, duplicates frames

Tags: centos, network-interface, duplicate, bonding

Two interfaces, `eth0` and `eth1` are part of a network bonding `bond0` on CentOS 6.

All worked well under CentOS 5, but after the upgrade to CentOS 6.6, keeping the same configuration, the network works fine but

- despite setting `/etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf` with `options mode=1` or even `mode=active-backup`, the status from `/proc/net/bonding/bond0` always shows `load balancing` (round-robin), not `active-backup` as it should.
- doing a ping to a LAN address (that belongs to `bond0` network) for the first time after a reboot, the first frame is `DUP!` (duplicated), the DUP doesn't happen anymore on further pings. Likely due to *round-robin* instead of *active-backup*

/etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf:

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 mode=1 miimon=100
```

ifcfg-bond0:

```
DEVICE=bond0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NETWORK=10.1.1.0
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=10.1.1.11
USERCTL=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

ifcfg-eth0:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=00:22:35:12:26:18
UUID=12fa32c2-e421-47f6-8d25-11414a664318
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
USERCTL=no
```

ifcfg-eth1:

```
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=00:22:35:12:26:19
UUID=12fa32c2-e421-47f6-8d25-11414a664319
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
USERCTL=no
```

All updates have been applied. NetworkManager is disabled.

The main problem seems now to be the mode, round-robin instead of active-backup.

Comment: One note is that `mode` in the module options has a typo. I don't think it's causing your problems but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: It might also be worth it to post the stack trace somehow so we can see what threads are involved in the panic.

Comment: @Bratchley actually a number of updates + BIOS seem to have fixed the kernel panic. However, whatever the options in `bonding.conf`, ie `mode=1` or `mode=active-backup`, the status from `/proc/net/bonding/bond0` always shows `load balancing` (round-robin). I'll edit the question.

Comment: It might be worth it to post that as a new question since it doesn't relate to the original issue with kernel panics or the DUP message. That would get more eyes on the problem since people see new questions before they see updated questions.

Comment: @Bratchley Added an answer that explains what happened. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some deeper investigation, found the problem for the round-robin and DUP problems. They are actually related.

- **round robin (0) instead of active-backup (1)**

On CentOS 5+, and seemingly especially 6.6, it recommended / preferred to use the `BONDING_OPTS` parameter directly in `ifcfg-bond0` (and not in the bonding module options, that makes sense)

```
DEVICE=bond0
...
BONDING_OPTS="mode=1 miimon=100"
```

(mode may be specified as '1' or as 'active-backup')
After adding the line, everything worked as expected.

- **duplicated *ping* frames**

In round-robin mode, both interfaces are used. And when the interfaces are connected to two different switches, the early *ping* replies may be duplicated

> It is not uncommon to observe a short burst of duplicated traffic when
>   the bonding device is first used, or after it has been idle for some
>   period of time.  This is most easily observed by issuing a "ping" to
>   some other host on the network, and noticing that the output from ping
>   flags duplicates (typically one per slave).
>
> For example, on a bond in active-backup mode with five slaves all
>   connected to one switch, the output may appear as follows:

```
    # ping -n 10.0.4.2
    PING 10.0.4.2 (10.0.4.2) from 10.0.3.10 : 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 10.0.4.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=13.7 ms
    64 bytes from 10.0.4.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=13.8 ms (DUP!)
```

> This is not due to an error in the bonding driver, rather, it is a
>   side effect of how many switches update their MAC forwarding tables.

After switching to active-backup, no more DUPs were observed.

This is explained in details in this invaluably knowledgeable documentation

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt